# get x and y components of ec public key using openssl

Tags: cryptography, openssl, ecc

I am generating a KeyPair for [ECC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography) from curve 'secp128r1' using openssl

Steps I followed :

- first I generated a private key using the command

  > openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp128r1 -noout -out private.pem
- then i viewed the corresponding public key using the command

  > openssl ec -in private.pem -text -noout

  which showed an output as :

  > read EC key
  >
  > > Private-Key: (128 bit)
  > >     priv:
  > >      00:9f:bf:2b:bd:06:86:3a:a1:bc:7c:3e:90:57:40:
  > >     f4:bc
  > >     pub: 
  > >      04:04:ce:24:34:d4:cb:f2:58:94:2f:8a:5f:06:d7:
  > >      3f:ed:5a:50:ef:fb:cc:b7:49:62:16:62:9e:aa:d5:
  > >      30:a8:a5
  > >     ASN1 OID: secp128r1

I want explicitly x and y components from the public key generated here, please can anyone suggest the correct way of doing this ?
The above public key is 264 bits long, hence cannot take(/split) it as is 
Thanks

Comment: Dupe of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60926/ecc-public-key-length-differs-from-bit-representation ; per http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5480#section-2.2 the first octet (04) means uncompressed, which is followed by X,Y cooordinates each exactly the field size rounded to octets, here 16 octets.

Comment: @dave_Thompson - I think you should provide an answer. It was good question and good information (and on the correct site!!!), and you should receive the benefit of a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [secp128r1](https://www.keylength.com/en/4/) is outdated. Use curves that give better security for today's standard. See [safecurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) by Daniel J. Bernstein and Tanja Lange.

An Elliptic Curve defined over a field of size *q* and every element -point- has two coordinates *X* and *Y*. The Elliptic Curve Secp128r1 has 2<sup>128</sup>-2<sup>97</sup>-1 size ℓ, i.e. number of points a little under 2^128. This means that we need 128-bit representation.

The public key which is also a point on the curve has two coordinates, therefore, we need to store two 128-bit.

If we look at the equation of the elliptic curve *Y<sup>2</sup>* = *X<sup>3</sup> + aX + b* where

```
 a = FFFFFFFD FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFF
 b = E87579C1 1079F43D D824993C 2CEE5E
```

if we know *X* from the equation we can find *Y*. Since we are working in a field the *Y* can have at most two square roots. *Y<sup>2</sup>* will have *y* or *-y* as the square root. This knowledge can be used to compress the representation of a point and it is called **point compression**. Just *x* coordinate and one bit to select *y* or *-y*. Now look at the base point (see [Certicom recommendation](https://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf))

```
 base point = 03 161FF752 8B899B2D 0C28607C A52C5B86
            = 04 161FF752 8B899B2D 0C28607C A52C5B86 CF5AC839 5BAFEB13 C02DA292 DDED7A83
```

The [first octet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480#section-2.2) determines the structure

- `04` means there is no compression
- `03` means there is a compression and select *y* as **positive**
- `02` means there is a compression and select *y* as **negative**

---

Now turn into OP's parameters;

> ```
> pub:
> 04:
> 04:ce:24:34:d4:cb:f2:58:94:2f:8a:5f:06:d7:3f:ed: -->X
> 5a:50:ef:fb:cc:b7:49:62:16:62:9e:aa:d5:30:a8:a5  -->Y
> ```

first octet `04` means there is no compression. The first line is the *X* coordinate and the second line is the *Y* coordinate of your public key.

What about the private key *n*? It is just a scalar -integer- between 0<=*n*<=ℓ

> priv:
> 00:9f:bf:2b:bd:06:86:3a:a1:bc:7c:3e:90:57:40:f4:bc

Therefore, the above number - not point - is your private key.

You can also use some web tools to extract this information.

- [8gwifi.org - Crypto Playground](https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp)

> **Note: please don't expose your private key.**